# Better method for converting int to short? (NULL if not possible)

Tags: c#, .net

I have following two approaches for converting `int` to `short?`.

1. First one fails if the value is not in short range.
2. The second approach works but it has a unnecessary `conversion to string`.

Is there a better method?

**EDIT**:

From the answer below:

> Int16 is just a subset of Int32 so you do not need any conversion to "intermediate" types.

**CODE**

```
//Approach 1
int vIn = 123456789;
short? vOut = Convert.ToInt16(vIn);
//Value was either too large or too small for an Int16.

//Approach 2
short? vOut2 = null;
int vIn2 = 123456789;
short number;
string characterRepresentationOfInt = vIn2.ToString();
bool result = Int16.TryParse(characterRepresentationOfInt, out number);
if (result)
{
    vOut2 = number;
}
```

Reference:

1. [Java: Conversion from int to short](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/corejava/dataconversion/int/inttoshort.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why you can't simply use the built-in conversion of the cast? Just add a check to be sure it's not out of range (if you want a `null` value instead of an exception).

```
short? ConvertToShort(int value)
{
    if (value < Int16.MinValue || value > Int16.MaxValue)
        return null;

    return (short)value;
}
```

About your approaches:

1. It works (of course) but you'll never get the `null` value and conversion may fail if `value` is outside the valid range of `Int16`.
2. It's terribly slow. Don't forget `Int16` is just a subset of `Int32` so you do not need any conversion to "intermediate" types.

Comment: Yeah.... "Int16 is just a subset of Int32 so you do not need any conversion to "intermediate" types." That's the key point I missed out... Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Sorry, i've posted the comment to the wrong answer. Nevermind.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of possible solutions.

Static helper method:

```
public static class Number
{
    public static bool TryConvertToShort(int value, out short result)
    {
        bool retval = false;
        result = 0;
        if (value > Int16.MinValue && value < Int16.MaxValue)
        {
            result = Convert.ToInt16(value);
            retval = true;
        }

        return retval;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
int a = 1234;
short b;
bool success = Number.TryConvertToShort(a, out b);
```

Extension method:

```
public static class ExtendInt32
{
    public static bool TryConvertToShort(this int value, out short result)
    {
        bool retval = false;
        result = 0;
        if (value > Int16.MinValue && value < Int16.MaxValue)
        {
            result = Convert.ToInt16(value);
            retval = true;
        }

        return retval;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
int a = 1234;
short b;
bool success = a.TryConvertToShort(out b);
```

You can also create a helper/extension method that doesn't fail gracefully and instead either returns a default value (0) or throws an exception.

```
public static short ConvertToShort(int value)
{
    short result;
    if (value > Int16.MinValue && value < Int16.MaxValue)
    {
        result = Convert.ToInt16(value);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new OverflowException();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote... I don't see any reason for downvote as well... [I have actually upvoted]

Comment: Let me guess: he asked for a null value if out of range and Convert.ToInt16() throws OverflowException by itself. That said I prefer, when applicable, a TryConvert approach to a null return value.

Comment: A nullable short is nothing more than a short and a bool, so why not just return one of those?

Comment: Why do you use > and < instead of >= and <=?